# Filtering count results in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How would I filter the count column in the query below to show me only rows that have a count > 1?

```
select FirstName, COUNT(*) as [CountTickets] from tblParkingTickets
group by FirstName  
order by [CountTickets] desc
```

This doesn't work:

```
select FirstName, COUNT(*) as [CountTickets] from tblParkingTickets
where [CountTickets] > 1
group by FirstName  
order by [CountTickets] desc
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with `HAVING`:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

`WHERE` filters before the group by (and therefore `COUNT` doesn't mean anything). `HAVING` filters after grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select FirstName, COUNT(*) mycount from tblParkingTickets
group by FirstName  
order by 2 desc) where mycount > 1
```

Try this one